# why Council page's member and chain state(council > members) are different?

Tags: council

for techcomm:

use technicalCommittee > setMembers(newMembers, prime, oldCount)

technicalCommittee page will synchronize this information(chainstate > technicalCommittee > members) in real time

but for council:

use council > setMembers(newMembers, prime, oldCount)

Council page's member and  chain state(council > members) are different. why?

---

clarify info add:

i use `https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/extrinsics` -> `council` -> `set_member(sudo)`

for members from:

```
chainstate -> council -> members(): Vec<AccountId32>
```

for members from:

```
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/council -> members
```

are different.

Answer (score 1):

i read polkadot.js code ,the logic of `https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/council -> members` data are from `elections.members`. so they are different.